# implement sklearn but get error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I try to use sklearn but get error lake that :

```
| Error     from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    | Error   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    | Error     from .bagging import BaggingClassifier
    | Error   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/bagging.py", line 20, in <module>
    | Error     from ..linear_model import LogisticRegression
    | Error   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    | Error     from .ridge import (Ridge, RidgeCV, RidgeClassifier, RidgeClassifierCV,
    | Error   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py", line 21, in <module>
    | Error     from .sag import sag_solver
    | Error   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/sag.py", line 14, in <module>
    | Error     from .sag_fast import sag, get_max_squared_sum
    | Error ImportError: cannot import name get_max_squared_sum
```

I use python2.7 mac OS. download scikit-learn-master in github then run `sudo python setup.py install`

The list I get is too long, so I only put a slice which I think maybe important

```
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/opt/local/lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/opt/local/lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/opt/local/lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/opt/local/lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  FOUND:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']

running install
running build
```

Comment: How did you install it? Pip?  What does `pip list` show?

Comment: I use python setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

from there documentation they mention these pre-requisites install them before installing scikit

```
Python (>= 2.6 or >= 3.3),
NumPy (>= 1.6.1),
SciPy (>= 0.9).
```

then run:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Comment: Yes, I already install these three before install scikit-learn .I don't use pip install -U scikit-learn because it tells me I already have scikit-learn in my python3.5lib, but I want to use python2.7 which is MAC OS contained

Comment: if you want pip for 2.7 install it using 

    sudo python get-pip.py

Comment: No,I don't mean that. Actually I  get :Successfully installed numpy-1.11.0 scikit-learn-0.17.1 scipy-0.17.0 using pip. but still can't use sklearn.

Comment: use pip freeze > packages.txt and check the file if numpy-1.11.0 scikit-learn-0.17.1 scipy-0.17.0 are present

Comment: I use :sudo pip freeze > packages.txt   and get this
The directory '/Users/guojingwei/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag

Comment: looks like you need to fix pip as it is not properly installed in your system , try sudo apt-get remove pip 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install python-pip

Comment: I finally solved this problem by using a script in github, it autumnally install a bag of libs for data mining. Still thanks for you kindly help.

Comment: @GUOJINGWEI hey I'm having the same issue, would you mind showing me the github please ?